# How to raise an error for `dtype` parameters in a class object

Tags: python, numpy, class, error-handling

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np

class circle(object):
    def __init__(self, radius=3, color='blue', data_type=np.float64):   # default values
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color 
        self.data_type = data_type
        
    if self.data_type not in [np.float32, np.float64]:
        raise ValueError('data_type should be np.float32 or np.float64 only')
        
    def add_radius(self, r):
        self.radius = self.radius + np.ceil(r, dtype=self.data_type)
        return(self.radius)
    
redcircle = circle(radius=10, color='red', data_type=np.float32)
redcircle.add_radius(2.323)
```

When I ran the code, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-27704fa7e57b> in <module>
----> 1 class circle(object):
      2     def __init__(self, radius=3, color='blue', data_type=np.float64):   # default values
      3         self.radius = radius
      4         self.color = color
      5         self.data_type = data_type

<ipython-input-39-27704fa7e57b> in circle()
      5         self.data_type = data_type
      6 
----> 7     if self.data_type not in [np.float32, np.float64]:
      8         raise ValueError('dtype should be np.float32 or np.float64 only')
      9 

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

How do I specify the `dtype` parameter in a class object so that I can raise an error if the `dtype` parameter value specified is not one which is accepted by the class object?

Many thanks in advance if anyone who knows.

Comment: (Not tested) I think line 7-8 should intent one more level, so they are part of __init__?

Comment: Thanks @NateB. You're right, indenting line 7-8 worked! If it's ok, can I ask why coding in lines like 7-8 needs to be indented whereas if I define a function inside the class (with `def`), these functions doesn't need to be indented?

Comment: Actually, I think I know the answer. All lines of code inside a class object should only be defined inside a function `def`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's structure is governed by completely level of indentation:

```
class circle(object):
    def __init__(self, radius=3, color='blue', data_type=np.float64):   # default values
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color 
        self.data_type = data_type
        # Python assumes this is the end of the __init__ function

    # because this next line is at the next higher level
    if self.data_type not in [np.float32, np.float64]:
        raise ValueError('data_type should be np.float32 or np.float64 only')
    
    # so the above is a fragment that will not run in __init__. 

    def add_radius(self, r):
        self.radius = self.radius + np.ceil(r, dtype=self.data_type)
        return(self.radius)
```

Does that answer your question?